# crontab file of a deleted user

Tags: cron, useradd

After removing the user, does the crontab added by that user gets removed as well?
I am asking this because I can see a user file called "abcuser" in the

```
/var/spool/cron/
```

When I cat the file, I can see the crons added by that user. The user no longer exist and the cron's won't work. But why does the crontab file is still there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `userdel` doesn't remove the user's cron, [`at`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-configure-batch-jobs/), and print jobs. To do it, uncomment the following line in `/etc/login.defs`:

```
USERDEL_CMD /usr/sbin/userdel_local
```

Here is an example of `userdel_local` script:

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 username"
    exit 1
fi

crontab -r -u $1
```

So, whenever you execute `userdel`, any cron jobs owned by the user will be remove.

Comment: +1 for that.  I learned something this morning; thanks, quanta!

Comment: The lack of deletion saved me some work after a PEBKAC event, but what's the historical reason for leaving those elements hanging around?